# Browser-sync not watching files

Tags: javascript, browser-sync

I am having problems with browser-sync. When I first installed, it was working, but now it no longer refreshs my index page when I make modifications to it and save. I noticed that when I start browser-sync, it no longer show the *"**[BS]Watching files..."*** message.

Have I missed any steps?

## Prompt output

[image]

Comment: Not related but you might want to have a look at new (ish) browser http://blisk.io - it does all file syncing within the browser, awesome tool

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Thanks for the tip! Indeed great tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blisk browser was a great option, as suggested by Darren, but now it is paid.
Got browser sync working with gulp as suggested by this discussion https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/646

Config:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
      browserSync.init({
          open: 'external',
          host: 'coolab.dev',
          proxy: 'coolab.dev/dashboard', 
          port: 3000
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add the command "--watch" when using the command line.

Like this:

```
browser-sync start --server --watch --files "*"
```